# Enlace directo a Nav tab de bootstrap

Tags: javascript

Os cuento, tengo este nav de bootstrap con unas pestañas:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="main-content-body main-content-body-profile card mg-b-20">
                            <nav class="nav main-nav-line">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#general">General</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#documentos">Documentos sin contabilizar</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#documentosc">Documentos contabilizados</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#mensajes">Mensajes asesor</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#notificaciones">Notificaciones</a>
```

Estoy intentando desde hace dias que cuando ponga en la utr url/xxx#general (por ejemplo) vaya directamente a la paguina con la pestaña del tab abierta.

Lo he intentado con javascrip sin exito, el ultimo codigo que he intentado es :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        activaTab('general');
      });

      function activaTab(tab){
        $('.main-nav-line a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
      };

</script>
```

No hay manera que funcione, no controlo JavaScript y me estoy mareando y necesito tener una url que cuando sea llamada abra la pagina con el TAB abierto directamente.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Accede a todos tus enlaces

2.- Agrega un evento de tipo click a todos tus enlaces

3.- Captura el enlace que estas clickeando y obten su atributo href

4.- Puedes reedirgir a la misma pagina o a otra en una nueva pestaña

Te dejo un ejemplo con codigo para que puedas comprenderlo mejor.

Me causa ruido lo que tienes en tu `href` cuando tienes algo como esto: `href="#notificaciones"` normalmente quieres navegar en la misma pagina a traves de su id

```
//ACCEDEMOS A TODOS TUS ENLACES
let enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("a");

//RECORREMOS LOS ENLACES Y A CADA UNO LES AGREGAMOS EL EVENTO CLICK
enlaces.forEach((enlace) => {
  enlace.addEventListener("click", function () {
    //window.location.href = this.getAttribute("href");
     window.open(this.getAttribute("href"), "_blank");
  });
});
```

Otro ejemplo de funcionalidad con tu propio código seria lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   activaTab('general');
});

function activaTab(tab){
  window.open(tab, "_blank");
};
```

Comment: No me funciona, y la segunda opción abre pestañas nuevas cuando pincho en los tab. No tengo manera de conseguir introducir una url o enlace directo terminado en #nombredeltab y que se abra la pagina con esa pestaña abierta.